# HTML5 background video will not play

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, html5-video, microsoft-edge

I have a problem with a HTML5 background video. The video is on the front page and should be started automatically without sound. after a click on a button, it should play with 20% volume.
My code works in Mozilla Firefox without any problems. But not in Safari or MS Edge. in Google Chrome only conditionally. When I enter the page, the video does not start, when i change to another site and go back to the home page, the video works.

I have already removed the JS Code for the volume and tested only with .mp4-video. Without success.

HTML:

```
<div id="video">
    <video loop="true" preload="none" autoplay="true">
        <source src=".../video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src=".../video.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
</div>
```

JS:

```
video_show();
function video_show() {
  $("#video video").each(function(){this.volume = 0.0;});
};
$("button1").click(function() {
  $("#video video").each(function(){this.volume = 0.2;});
});
$("button2").click(function() {
  $("#video video").each(function(){this.volume = 0.0;});
});
```

CSS:

```
#video video {
  height: auto;
  left: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: IIRC you also need the `muted` attribute to auto-play the video without user interacion

Comment: That's the solution for my problem in MS Edge and Google Chrome. And it also works with

`$("#video video").each(function(){this.muted = true;});`

I read that Safari needs the `controls` attribute for `autoplay`. But that don't solve my issue - any idea?

Comment: which version of Safari? FWIW this works fine for me in Safari 12.0: `<video muted autoplay>
    <source src="trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>`

Comment: It works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Below is the updated code which is working as expected in Edge and Firefox.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
#video video {
 
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
 
 
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function video_show() {
  $("#video video").each(function(){this.volume = 0.0;});

};

function play_sound() {
  $("#video video").each(function(){this.volume = 0.2;});

};
function mute_sound() {
  $("#video video").each(function(){this.volume = 0.0;});

};


</script>
</head>
<body onload="video_show()">
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Play Sound" onclick="play_sound()"/>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Mute Sound" onclick="mute_sound()"/>
<div id="video">
    <video loop="true"  autoplay>
       <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
    </video>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Further, You can try to modify code as per your requirement.

Note:- Make a test locally. Stack Overflow output will not play the video properly.

Comment: Another video format don't solve my problem in Safari. Google Chrome needs the attribute `muted` for `autoplay`.